# CodeIgniter Session will not be saved

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cart

Experts,

i have a little Problem with my sessions. I want to save my login data into the session like this:

***checklogin Controller***

```
$user = $this->user_model->user($email, $password);
$user["logged_in"] = TRUE;
var_dump($this->session->set_userdata($user)); // return NULL? is this correct?
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata()); //return the correct data
```

Now the Session is saved up to a redirect.

***Other Controller***

```
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata()); // return session_id,… and a empty user_data array
```

I think I have the same Problem with the Shopping Cart Class.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you added the code to start the session? You may need to add `session_start();` above the controllers class declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
$user = $this->user_model->user($email, $password);
$user["logged_in"] = TRUE;
$this->session->set_userdata('user',$user);  //set session of users with a name user.
```

to get the session value u can do..

```
print_r($this->session->userdata('user')); // prints the user session array..
```

[read more](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) about sessions in CI

Answer (score 4):

I dont know why, but i think my story will help someone who facing the same problem.
My problem is just because I forgot to downgrade my Wamp php version, its php 7.1. Looks like my CI not support php 7.1 or higher. So just a few click to downgrade my php, my problem **solved**.

Answer (score 3):

I added session_start() in the main index.php file. Worked like a charm afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The `set_userdata()` function does not have a return value, so it is correct to display `null` on `var_dump()`.

In order to save custom data to user's session you should check the manual [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

The parameter it accepts must be an array.

Answer (score 0):

hmm try add  to `ci->session`  and then get data

//assign the CodeIgniter object to a variable

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct ();                     
    $this->ci = & get_instance ();
        }
```

//add data to ci session

```
function test(){
     $this->ci->session->set_userdata($user)
}
```

in the other controller  assign the `CodeIgniter` object to a variable

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct ();                     
    $this->ci = & get_instance ();
        }
```

and get the ci user data

```
$this->ci->session->all_userdata()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue when I want to rerun an old website that was built formerly using **CI 3.0.6** on a server running **PHP 7.3**.

I have set a session in one controller.

```php
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', TRUE);
```

Then, the other controllers that are accessed after that cannot retrieve the information while a new record in the session table in the database is stored.

```php
empty($_SESSION['logged_in']); // true
empty($this->session->logged_in); // true
```

The solution that works for me is as follows.

1. Set a higher size for the `id` column in the CI session table. For example, our session table name is `ci_sessions`.

```
ALTER TABLE ci_sessions CHANGE id id varchar(128) NOT NULL;
```

2. Replace the current CI `system` directory with newer version. In my case, it works with the `system` directory from **CI 3.1.10**.

In summary, a newer CI version is required to be able to interact well with newer PHP (7.1+). It has a longer `id` value for the stored session record. Rather than downgrading your PHP version, it is better to upgrade the CI version.